Is it good practice to place decoupling capacitors near connector pins?
I’ve seen some notes online about placing decoupling capacitors near I/O connector pins, as well as some saying power lines of connector pins.
Despite this, I feel that I haven’t often seen capacitors next to connectors in my experience. What is the standard practice for capacitors and connector placement?

A general rule-of-thumb for EMC filters is that they should be placed at the cables side / connector side, not at the load side, otherwise noise often still enters and leaves the load due to near-field coupling. For ESD filters, it's also beneficial to place them near the source, not the load. I believe these two considerations eventually became the rule of thumb of, "place some decoupling capacitor near connectors, just in case they're needed."

There is no standard practice.
It depends on the connector and what it is used for.
You put a cap if you need it for some reason, or leave it out if there is no reason to put it.
In some cases it's a necessity to provide bypassing for some reason, like to pass through some compliance test for a standard, for example EMI/EMC/ESD testing or otherwise, like for example meeting hotplugging requirements.
Sometimes a bypass cap is even mandated by a standard. For example, USB Type-C cables have them in their plugs too, or otherwise the cable is not compliant with the standard.

People may put them near connectors if there is a possibility of ESD from external wiring damaging the chips on your circuit board. After all, you ideally want the transient to be dealt with at the edge of your circuit rather than let it conduct down tracks that may induce problems in parallel circuits.

Electrolytics near power inlet connectors can help reduce the overshoot from the interaction of long wire run inductance and low-ESR ceramic converter input caps (see: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an88f.pdf), but there's no "standard" advice about putting caps on connector pins.
Generally, you want capacitance on data lines to be as low as possible to give sharp, fast transitions consonant with ringing, drive strength, and EMI considerations.
